# header location for php going to 404

Tags: php, html, header

Working on a simple sign in page where the user enters the name and password. Right now I just have it so when the user enters the usrname and password it should redirect to my `success.html` page where it will just print out `<h2>successful login</h2>`. Whenever I try to click the log in button, I can see in my browser that it is catching the username and password but it shows a 404 page. Any help would be appreciated. I will put my code down below for both of the files.

```
`home.html`

<head>
<title>Hangman Home Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>

<?php

   #not empty
    #atleast 6 characters long


    # array holds errors
    $errors = array[];

    # validation starts here

    if(count($errors) == 0){

        # redirect to the game page
        header('Location:success.html');
        exit();
    }


    ?>

<div class="header">
<div class="a">Hangman</div>
</div>
<div class="topnav">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!--column start here -->
<div class="hi">
<table id="leader">
<tr>
<th><img src="crown.gif"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Leader Board</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1st. John : 4 guess</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2nd. Smith : 6 Guesses</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3rd. Tom : 7 Guesses</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4th. Allen : 8 Guesses</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- form start here -->
<br>
<br>


<div class="b">Think You Can Beat #1 ?</div>

<center><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Play Now!!!</button></center>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
<form method="post" class="modal-content animate">
<div class="imgcontainer">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
<img src="hang1.gif" alt="logo" class="avatar">
</div>


<div class="container">
</p>

<label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>


<label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

<button type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
</div>
</form>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
<span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
</div>
   </form>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>

 `success.html`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" 
 content="width=device- 
   width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<h2> Successful Connection!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't send a `header()` after sending any output to the browser.

Comment: can you explain to me how I can just validate the username and password and if they are what I want them to be then it goes to another page? @ivanivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, Where is the doctype and html tag for home.html? And the next is that forms should contain an action attribute that should specify the location/page where the information should be sent to like
    `<form action="success.html" method="POST" class="modal-content animate">` 
if success.html and home.html are in the same directory.
action attribute takes empty strings if you want the form to be submitted to the same page as he form.
Although it is not necessary but not specifying it creates unexpected problems sometimes. Read more basics about forms at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp